# how do I parse react component in angularjs directive?

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, angularjs-directive, gulp, eslint

I am trying to migrate my angularJS app to React. So I am trying to create an angular directive which injects react component. My eslint or gulp is unable to parse the directive and giving me

> Parsing error: Unexpected token <

here is the directive
[image]

my eslint file config is as below

[image: my eslint file config is as below]

I think I have added the necessary config. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: are you using babel?

Comment: @azium yes I have `"babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.22.0",` installed.

Comment: and you have a gulpfile that's running all those babel plugins?

Answer (score 0):

I can't really tell you how to shut up the linter complain, but over here I can see there is mistake in the code that can easily fix this up. Inside angularjs directive link function you can get linked directive DOM from `link` function second parameter (`el`), you can query that DOM specifically, inspite of querying whole document.

```
link: (scope, el, attrs) {
  const reactApp = el.find('#reactapp');
  //....
}
```

Comment: Okay I changed that, but the `ReactDOM.render(<Layout/>, reactapp);` is the line where I am facing the error. Angular unable to parse <Layout />. Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: @UIguy89 can you try to setup [mentioned `rules`](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/459#issuecomment-194433665) inside `.eslint` file

Comment: Actually adding the `React.createElement` worked but now I have a different error. `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined` for `var React = require('react');` which I am working on. Thanks

Comment: Let me know if you face any other issue.